# Como posso fazer pra esse cálculo ser realizado em todos os objects do array e me retornar o valor multiplicado pelo length da tabela?

Tags: javascript, array, funções, ecmascript-6

> Preciso que o cálculo seja realizado em todos os objects antes de me retornar o valor pelo length da tabela (OBS: é só um desafio que estou participando, não estou usando banco de dados).

```js
function desafio() {

  let tabela = [

    {
      preco: 10,
      qtd: 5,
      peso: 5
    },

    {
      preco: 2,
      qtd: 8,
      peso: 4
    },

    {
      preco: 25,
      qtd: 15,
      peso: 2
    }

  ]

  let clientes = [

    {
      email: "Ana@hotmail.com"
    },
    {
      email: "Bruno@hotmail.com"
    },
    {
      email: "Carlos@hotmail.com"
    }

  ]

  let calculo = ((tabela[0].preco * tabela[0].qtd) * tabela[0].peso) / clientes.length

  form = Math.round(calculo)

  let total = form * tabela.length

  if (clientes.length === 0) {
    console.log("Digite o email dos clientes")
  } else {

  }

  for (let i = 0; i < clientes.length; i++) {

    console.log(`${clientes[i].email} = ${total}`)
  }
}
desafio()
```

Comment: Eu não entendi a pergunta. Poderia esclarecer?

Comment: Eu preciso que esse cálculo que eu declarei seja feito em todos os objetos do array antes de retornar a multiplicação pelo total de itens dentro do array. Quando me refiro aos objetos do array, falo dos itens que estão entre { } e o cálculo que eu quero retornar de cada um deles está representado em "let calculo =", logo abaixo de tabela e cliente. Esse código que enviei está me retornando o cálculo somente de 1 objeto, sendo que no código tem 3, novamente, representados por { }, ele está interpretando que precisa fazer o cálculo somente do primeiro e já multiplicar por tabela.length.

Comment: Coloca isso na pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, nao entendi muito bem sua pergunta, mas acredito que seja isso que voce queira fazer.

```js
function desafio() {

  let tabela = [

    {
      preco: 10,
      qtd: 5,
      peso: 5
    },

    {
      preco: 2,
      qtd: 8,
      peso: 4
    },

    {
      preco: 25,
      qtd: 15,
      peso: 2
    }

  ]

  let clientes = [

    {
      email: "Ana@hotmail.com"
    },
    {
      email: "Bruno@hotmail.com"
    },
    {
      email: "Carlos@hotmail.com"
    }

  ]

  if (clientes.length > 0) {

    clientes.forEach((element, i) => {

      let calculo = Math.round(((tabela[i].preco * tabela[i].qtd) * tabela[i].peso) / clientes.length);

      console.log(element.email + " - total: " + calculo)

    })

  } else {
    console.log('por favor digite um email')
  }



}
desafio()
```

Comment: Eu acho que está certo, mas a pergunta está bem difícil de entender.

Comment: Quase isso, só que eu preciso os 3 objects somem o resultado do cálculo e depois dividam igualmente entre os emails.